# Is covariance a commutative operator? Is it the reason why a covariance matrix is a symmetric n by n matrix?

Tags: covariance

Having that $x$ and $y$ are two random variables with the covariance

$\operatorname{cov}(x,y) = E[(x - E(x))(y-E(y))] $

This means to me that

$\operatorname{cov}(x,y) = E[(y - E(y))(x-E(x))] $

which means

$\operatorname{cov}(x,y) = \operatorname{cov}(y,x)$ and that covariance is a commutative operator.

Having now that the covariance of a column vector $v = \begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
v_n\\
\end{pmatrix}$ is defined as
$\operatorname{cov}(v) = E[(v - E(v)).(v - E(v))^T]$

which means

$ \operatorname{cov}(v) = E[( 
\begin{pmatrix} 
v_1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
v_n\\
\end{pmatrix} - E(v)).\begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
v_1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
v_n\\
\end{pmatrix}- E(v))\end{pmatrix} ^T]$

which means

$ \operatorname{cov}(v) = E[( 
\begin{pmatrix} 
v_1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
v_n\\
\end{pmatrix} - E(v)).\begin{pmatrix}
(v_1 - E(v_1)) . . . (v_n - E(v_n))
\end{pmatrix}]$

which means

$ \operatorname{cov}(v) = E[ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
v_1 - E(v_1)\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
v_n - E(v_n)\\
\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}
(v_1 - E(v_1)) . . . (v_n - E(v_n))
\end{pmatrix}]$

which means

$ \operatorname{cov}(v) =
\begin{pmatrix} 
\operatorname{cov}(v_1,v_1)           .  .   .             \operatorname{cov}(v_1,v_n) \\
.                                                                                    \\
.                                                                               \\
.                                                                                     \\
\operatorname{cov}(v_n,v_1)           .  .   .             \operatorname{cov}(v_n,v_n) \\
\end{pmatrix} $

Let's now call M the covariance matrix $\operatorname{cov}(v)$ of the column vector $v = \begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
v_n\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Can I now just say M is a symmetric n by n matrix such as the $(i,j)th$ element is the covariance of the variable $v_i$ and $v_j$ ?

Is this a solid proof for such a statement? Or did I forget something?

Comment: Yes, $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = \text{Cov}(Y,X)$, and covariance matrices are always symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covariance is a commutative operator.

A covariance matrix is always a symmetric $n$ by $n$ matrix.